# How to restart database with Spring Boot/MySQL/Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I created a small web application with Spring Boot, Hibernate, Spring Security tools and now I want to test it in browser. Everything works great I guess but there is a small problem that I can not to solve by myself. I want to my DataBase populates its automatically after disconnection/connection with populatorDB.sql to not create/delete my data again. It means, when I add/delete new data into DB while testing it in browser, I have them in DB, than I disconnect/connect and I do not have new data in DB only my standard set with populatorDB.sql.

PopulatorDB.sql

```
DELETE FROM lardi.user_roles;
DELETE FROM lardi.contacts;
DELETE FROM lardi.users;

INSERT INTO lardi.users
(login,password,full_name) VALUES
  ('Bill', '112233', 'user'),
  ('John', '112233', 'user'),
  ('Mark', '112233', 'user');

INSERT INTO lardi.user_roles
(role,user_id) VALUES
  ('ROLE_USER',1),
  ('ROLE_USER',2),
  ('ROLE_USER',3);

INSERT INTO lardi.contacts
(first_name, last_name, patronymic, mobile_phone_number, home_phone_number, address, email, user_id) VALUES
  ('Ivan','Ivanov','Ivanovych','+380(66)1234567','','USA','bill@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Petro','Petrov','Petrovych','+380(66)9876543','+380(44)1122334','USA','mark@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Sydor','Sydorov','Sydorovych','+380(99)1234567','','USA','barak@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Mykola','Mykolaiov','Mykolaiovych','+380(99)9876543','','USA','michel@gmail.com', 1),
  ('Aleksandr','Aleksandrov','Aleksandrovych','+380(50)5557799','+380(44)0000009','UK','david@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Vasyl','Vasyliov','Vasyliovych','+380(00)1100999','','USA','steve@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Viktor','Viktorov','Viktorovych','+380(00)2244888','','USA','tim@gmail.com', 2),
  ('Kostia','Konstantynov','Konstantynovych','+380(69)8881188','+380(44)1111119','USA','jim@gmail.com', 3),
  ('Anton','Antonov','Antonovych','+380(67)9000001','','UK','david@gmail.com', 3);
```

DB config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.model");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lardi?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setUsername( "root" );
        dataSource.setPassword( "2940063" );
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:validation");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer(DataSource dataSource){
        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("populatorDB.sql"));
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(databasePopulator);
        dataSourceInitializer.setEnabled(true);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer(){
        final PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setSystemPropertiesMode(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE );
        return props;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could put a schema.sql and data.sql inside the src/main/resources and use the default JDBC Initializer.

More details in: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html, section 75.3

Comment: but I do not have `profile("populatedb")` in Spring Boot app. I want to restart DB automaticly with the help of populatorDB.sql everytime before connection.

Comment: By connection/disconnection you mean when the user logs in and out?

Comment: No, I mean while running application in Tomcat.

Comment: Ok, so when you restart your tomcat you lose all the data inserted, right?

Comment: Actually no. I have all inserted data after restarting Tomcat. I want lose them after restarting Tomcat and populate my DB automaticly with populatorDB.sql

Comment: In this case, I think you could call your DataSourceInitializer manually:

Comment: if you want to lose the data you must replace "update" with spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop.

Comment: Good Georges, I didn't see he was using update, update would never drop the current content.

Comment: @Georges van houtte I lose all the data in DB without population.

Comment: I used 'create-drop' ddl but it works without population

Comment: so its just creating tables with not data or not even tables are created ? Also show your application structure tree.

Comment: @Georges van houtte all tables are created but they are empty. I guess my populatorDB.sql is not working.

Comment: @BogdanZeleniuk have you tried using the schema.sql and data.sql spring boot default JDBC initializer?
Take a look at section 75.3 in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Comment: @Alessandro Moraes I replaced the name `populatorDB.sql` that I had before to `data.sql` accordantly to `spring.io docs` and it works correct. You can post this answer and I will mark it as right. Thanks `you` and `@Georges van houtte` for help anyway.

Comment: @BogdanZeleniuk I edited my answer to the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove the "update" property and replace it with

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
```

The hibernate.ddl-auto property will create the table (based on your declared entities annotated with `@Entity` ) and when the app finishes, it will drop it.